# Mongohub RegExp error

Tags: regex, mongodb

just a short question: Using rockmongo I can execute a query like

{name: /test/i} and it will find all results containing "test" in the name field.

Mongohub just tells me: unexpected char in the current parser context - "{"name": /test/}"

Doesn't mongohub support regular expressions? I am using the fork on https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regexp, but you have to use strict json format : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON

So far that's the only regression from the original fork. I wish to have enough time to implement the tengen format.

See : https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac/issues/46

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this page! Works, though I find it more complicated than standard js expressions :)